# Unable to detect Camera when trying to connect to edge impulse for image detection

Tags: camera

I am using a raspberry pi v2 camera on a raspberry pi 4 8GB RAM board.  I am currently trying to connect to a project on edge impulse I built but when I try to connect the terminal says that no camera is detected.

output from the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ edge-impulse-linux
Edge Impulse Linux client v1.3.5

[SER] Using microphone hw:1,0
Failed to initialize linux tool Error: Cannot find any webcams, run this command with --disable-camera to skip selection
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/edge-impulse-linux/build/cli/linux/linux.js:435:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I have gone through several tutorials but none of them worked.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try to do one of the following options:

if you have installed Raspbian with GUI:

- start up your Raspberry Pi.
- go to the main menu and open the Raspberry Pi Configuration tool;
- select the Interfaces tab and ensure that the camera is enabled;
- reboot your Raspberry Pi.

OR

using the command line in terminal:

- type `sudo raspi-config`;
- use the cursor keys to select and open Interfacing Options;
- select Camera and follow the prompt to enable the camera;
- reboot your Raspberry Pi.